Livewire message.processed hook not triggered after DOM updates in a component
I am using Laravel Livewire in my project, and I need to reinitialize some DOM elements (e.g., dropdowns, ...) after Livewire updates the DOM. However, the Livewire.hook('message.processed', ...) does not seem to be triggered, as the alert in my script never shows.
Here is my code:


<div class="tf-section seller" id="top-recharge">
    <div class="themesflat-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="heading-section">
                    <h2 class="tf-title pb-30">Top nạp
                        <span class="dropdown" id="select-day">
                            <span class="btn-selector tf-color" id="selectedDay">
                                <span>{{ $selectedDay }}</span>
                            </span>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($days as $day)
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="day-item" data-day="{{ $day }}" wire:click="changeDay('{{ $day }}')">{{ $day }}</span>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </span>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="swiper-container seller seller-slider2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        @foreach ($topRecharges as $index => $recharge)
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <div class="tf-author-box text-center">
                                    <div class="author-avatar">
                                        <img src="{{ asset('front/green/images/avatar/avatar-' . str_pad($index + 1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.png') }}" alt="" class="avatar">
                                        <div class="number">{{ $index + 1 }}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="author-infor">
                                        <h5><a href="#">{{ $recharge->name }}</a></h5>
                                        <h6 class="price gem style-1">{!! zi_format_currency($recharge->total_amount) !!}</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next seller-next over active"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev seller-prev over"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@script
<script>
    Livewire.hook('message.processed', () => {
        alert('This alert never triggers'); // This alert never triggers
        dropdown('#select-day');
    });
</script>
@endscript



Livewire Component:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class LivewireTopRecharge extends Component
{
    public $days = ['tuần', 'tháng'];
    public $selectedDay = 'tuần';
    public $topRecharges = [];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->loadTopRecharges();
    }

    public function changeDay($day)
    {
        $this->selectedDay = $day;
        $this->loadTopRecharges();
    }

    private function loadTopRecharges()
    {
        $dateRange = now();
        if ($this->selectedDay === 'ngày') {
            $dateRange = now()->startOfDay();
        } elseif ($this->selectedDay === 'tuần') {
            $dateRange = now()->startOfWeek();
        } elseif ($this->selectedDay === 'tháng') {
            $dateRange = now()->startOfMonth();
        }

        $this->topRecharges = DB::table('transaction_histories')
            ->join('shop_customers', 'shop_customers.id', '=', 'transaction_histories.shop_customer_id')
            ->select(
                'shop_customers.name',
                DB::raw('SUM(transaction_histories.amount) as total_amount')
            )
            ->where('transaction_histories.transaction_date', '>=', $dateRange)
            ->groupBy('shop_customers.id')
            ->orderByDesc('total_amount')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get()->toArray();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->dispatch('swiper-reinit');
        return view('livewire.livewire-top-recharge');
    }
}

Problem:

The Livewire.hook('message.processed', ...) is not being triggered.
I need to reinitialize the dropdown (#select-day) and Swiper slider after Livewire updates the DOM.

Does anyone know why the message.processed hook is not being triggered and how I can properly reinitialize DOM elements after Livewire updates?
